# Python OOP Factory Pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, factory

I am still learning OOP Design Pattern and everything I have read so far says that Factory Patterns are commonly used. I am still trying to learn this pattern. For my program I am creating an Abstract Factory called "person" and my factory called "personFactory" should let you create different types of people (Users, Customers, Plumbers, etc...). With my current code I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fName'
```

This is my code:

person.py

```
import abc

class person:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    fName = ""
    mName = ""
    lName = ""
    address = ""
    city = ""
    state = ""
    zipcode = ""
    email = ""
    phone = ""
    dob = None
```

personFactory.py

```
from person import person

class personFactory(person):

    def createUser(self):
        uName = ""
        password = ""
        role = ""
        def __init__(self,uName,password,role):
            self.uName = uName
            self.password = password
            self.role = role
        def login(uName,password):
            if(uName == self.uName and password == self.password):
                return "Logged In"
            else:
                return "Did not log in"
        def logout():
            return "Logout"

    def createCustomer(self):
        items = []
        balace = 0
        def __init__(self,balance):
            self.balance = balance
        def AddToCart(item):
            self.items.append(item)
            print("Item added")
        def Order(items):
            totalprice = 0
            for item in items:
                totalprice =+ item.price
            return totalprice
        def Pay(payment):
            self.balance =- payment
            return self.balance
```

main.py

```
import personFactory

class main():
    pf = personFactory.personFactory()
    user1 = pf.createUser()
    user1.fName = "John"
    user1.lName = "Smith"
    user1.uName = "jSmith"
    user1.password = "Jamestown"

    customer1 = pf.createCustomer()
    customer1.fName = "George"
    customer1.lName = "Washington"
    customer1.balance = 100

main()
```

I'm not sure why fName is a NoneType. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't call it because `personFactory` is a class. In order to call it with your current code you will first need to create an instance of ithe class before calling the method. ie. `pf = personFactory()`, then `pf.createUser()`. BTW you should follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding conventions for naming classes, methods, and functions.

Comment: Thank you! I actually had to add pf = personFactory.personFactory() and remove __init__ from person.py. I will definitely look over the PEP 8 document. The following changes have still not made my program run. Please review my edits.

Comment: You need to read your code very carefully and understand what types you have and how you're attempting to use them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: What do you think a function within a function does?

Comment: I think you need to learn Python itself and "regular" OOP much better before attempting to implement any of the relatively advanced Design Patterns because the code in your question has a large number of very fundamental coding programming problems. A big glaring one, for starters, is that all your `personFactory` class methods do nothing but define local variables and functions that are never used in them (or anywhere else) and don't return any results, which is why you're getting the `AttributeError` — _not_ because `fName` is a `NoneType`, as you apparently think.

Comment: So more advice: Don't fundamentally modify the code in your question changing it so it effectively becomes a completely different one. Take what you have after the modification and if you can figure out what new thing is wrong, then post the changed code as a new separate question.

Comment: @martineau define what you mean by "learn Python itself" and "regular OOP"... The reason my some of the methods are never used, is because this is an example, not an actual program. Also the reason why I was getting an error is because createUser and createCustomer needed to be a class instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You have the constructor inside the create_user method. As Ignacio was saying the **init** function must be outside of the create_user function, in order for you to pass the name, pass and role to the person_factory object at creation.

Or alternatively you could pass all those value to the create_user method as arguments and leave the class constructor out of the work.

Could be something like this...

class personFactory(person):

```
  def __init__(self,uName,password,role):
        self.uName = uName
        self.password = password
        self.role = role

def createUser(self):
    user = Person()
    user.type = "user"
    user.uName = self.uName
    user.password = self.password
    user.role = role
    return user
```

Or...

class personFactory(person):

```
  def createUser(self, uName, password, role):
       user = Person()
       user.type = "user"
       user.uName = uName
       user.password = password
       user.role = role
       return user
```

I would also suggest that you made use of inheritance and made concrete classes based on your abstract classes that represent each of your objects.

Like...

```
class User(Person):

      def __init__(name, password, role):
          self.name = name
          self.type = "User"
          self.password = password
```

So you can have a User class, and a Customer class, and each method of your factory can create the corresponding object, instead of a regular Person.